# The markup in the document following the root must be well-formed (Cannot delete extra line)

Tags: android, eclipse

Good evening, I am new to studying Java and XML for mobile applications and have a quick question for you guys.

I am trying to edit an XML file here and the error "The markup in the document following the root must be well-formed" appears on one of the lines (The last one)

So I opt to delete the last line from the code but whenever I delete it, it just reappears and prevents me from compiling the program. Can anyone help by answering why this is happening? Your help would be very much appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text=""/>

    </LinearLayout>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></menu>  <----- (this is the line that keeps coming back after being deleted)
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the xml file and recreate it from scratch.

Try crtl+shift+F to format document.

Hope it will help.